# What is the lifetime of the torch.manual_seed?

Tags: pytorch

I was using torch.manual_seed() in jupyter notebook. After removing this line of code and re-running my training code (which uses randomness in weight initialization), I saw different results.

It seems torch.manual_seed immediately became unset even though the python runtime remained the same. What are the rules for when it becomes obsolete?

Answer (score 0):

It is not about life time, it is about random generator mechanics. `manual_seed` resets generator's internal state, not setting up some fancy flag. Control flow reach it, - state resets to some fixed value.  Without said line, generator keeps it's state whatever it was at the moment, so you get different result.